# Share icons in blogger post

Tags: post, share, blogger

I've managed to replace some of the icons on the page, but I'm having issues with the ones related to blog posts, the icons you click to share the posts in your social network pages.

```
<a class='fac-art' expr:href='&quot;http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=&quot; + data:post.url + &quot;&amp;title=&quot;+ data:post.title' onclick='window.open(this.href, &apos;windowName&apos;, &apos;width=600, height=400, left=24, top=24, scrollbars, resizable&apos;); return false;' rel='nofollow' target='_blank'><i class='fa fa-facebook'/><span class='resp_del'> Facebook</span></a>
```

That's one of the codes, and here is the blog page: https://eliezerh.blogspot.com/2018/10/o-empreendedor-destemido-e-um-mito-por.html

As I understand, and managed to change some of those icons in a different section, you use the  piece and replace, as example facebook with whatever icon you want instead... but nothing I do seems to work.

Can anyone please give me ideas?

Thanks so much for your support.

Best,

Eliezer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to identify `font-family` property as `FontAwesome` for `.fa:before` like the following

*Add to CSS code*

```
.share-box .fa:before {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
}
```